# Alfresco 6.2 community won't start

Tags: java, tomcat, alfresco

I am using Community 6.2  on Tomcat9 openjdk version "11.0.9.1" 2020-11-04
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.9.1+1-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.20.04)

I have deployed it old-school as a war in /webapps

When I start tomcat, there are NO errors in the logs. I can see that /share starts up successfully,  but /alfresco stops at this line:

```
INFO  [management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [main] Starting 'Messaging' subsystem, ID: [Messaging, default]
```

I get no response from Tomcat.  It just sits there.  share does not work either.

the tomcat ./shutdown command does not work either, saying there is no listener on the shutdown port.  There are no other tomcats running. I have to kill the instance manually.  It's like tomcat crashes.

I tried deleting alf_data and the DB scheema and start over, but no luck.

Would anyone know what is going on?  Or a place to start looking?

Comment: See https://hub.alfresco.com/t5/alfresco-content-services-forum/endeless-starting-of-messaging-subsystem/td-p/225851 - I think you either need to disable messaging or have ActiveMQ setup. Annoyingly Alfresco doesn't warn if it gets stuck trying to talk to ActiveMQ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you installed [ActiveMQ](http://%20%20%5B1%5D:%20https://docs.alfresco.com/content-services/6.2/install/zip/) ? It is needed when installing community 6.2 manually.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have disabled the dir.keystore in alfresco-global.properties and also the secureComms value to none in global properties,solrcore.properties and solr.in.cmd.

**Global Properties:**

```
 #dir.keystore=${dir.root}/keystore
 # none, https
 alfresco.secureComms=none
```

**In solr.in.cmd**

```
Since we are setting up with no SSL, this property need to be set to none. Default is https
set SOLR_ALFRESCO_SECURECOMMS=none
```

**In solrcore.properties**

```
# none, https
alfresco.secureComms=none
```